# Biztalk and ODP.net: connection pools and connection strings

Tags: connection, biztalk, odp.net, pool

We have a problem with our BizTalk applications with receive locations and send ports connecting to an oracle database. We run out of connections.

I don't know why, but original developers used both WCF-Custom and WCF-OracleDB, but I think both use ODP.NET as the ADO.NET provider.

Since, in ADO.NET and certainly in ODP.NET, connection pools are keyed on the connection string (exact string match, I think), a connection pool could logically be shared among send ports and receive locations. Since we don't have control of the connection string itself, we have to assume that connection strings in the adapters are consistently generated from one port to the other.

My questions are:

1- Am I right to assume that receive locations and send ports can share connection pools, as long as they run on the same host instance, and

2- Would it be a good idea to group similar ports and locations (the ones using the same connections strings) into one host instance?

Thank you,
Michel

Comment: FYI, WCF-OracleDB is just a first class Adapter wrapper for the oracleDbBinding so they are effectively the same.

Comment: You say you run out of connections, do you mean connections on client or server side?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the below website, the connection pool is indeed determined via the uniqueness of the connection string:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

(See "Specifying Pooling parameters")

One way to tackle this problem or at least give you a better insight, would be to enable ODP.NET tracing and performance counters. This will allow you a clear view on how many connections are being used in the pool(s).

For more information on how to enable those, see:
http://blog.ilab8.com/2011/09/02/odp-net-pooling-and-connection-request-timed-out/

Comment: Please consider to upvote any helpful replies and accept any answers. That is the idea behind the website ;-)

Comment: I can't I need 15 reputation

Answer (score -2):

Set `pooling=false` on the connection string.